# Django deployed on Elastic Beanstalk intermittently hangs on login

Tags: amazon-web-services, django, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have a demo django application that is on an Elastic Beanstalk instance that I am showing, and I've had weird intermittent behavior. Sometimes I get stuck at the login menu (the whole site requires authentication), wherein I am temporarily become unable to login. Maybe the server keeps restarting (this happened twice within a half hour interval)?

Configurations were followed to the tee here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

It doesn't specify what server is used in pushing, so I'm a bit at loss for how to debug this behavior and resolve it. How do I stop this:

```
eb health

WebServer                         Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.$
total      ok    warning  degraded  severe    info   pending  unknown
2        2        0        0        0        0        0        0


eb status

Environment details for: legalforms
Application name: django
Region: us-west-1
...
Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.6
Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
...    
Updated: 2018-05-07 22:31:47.885000+00:00
Status: Ready
Health: Green
Alert: There is a newer version of the platform used by your environment.
```